# Clarification Needed on Selecting the Farthest Right Point 'c' in Lemma 3.5 of Chapter 3 from Stein's Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I'm reading chapter 3 of Stein's Real Analysis and have come across Lemma 3.5, which states:

> **Lemma 3.5**
> Suppose $G$ is real-valued and continuous on $\mathbb R$.
> Let $E$ be the set of points $x$ such that
> $$ G(x+h) > G(x) \quad \text{ for some } h = h_x > 0. $$
>
> If $E$ is non-empty, then it must be open, and hence can be written as a countable disjoint union of open intervals $E = \bigcup \left( a_k, b_k \right)$.
> If $\left( a_k, b_k \right)$ is a finite interval in this union, then
> $$ G(b_k) - G(a_k) = 0. $$

While reading the proof of the lemma, I'm having difficulty with an argument, and I've stuck at that part.
In the proof, the author claims that if $G(b_k) < G(a_k)$, then due to continuity, there exists a point $c$ in the interval $(a_k, b_k)$ where $G(c) = \frac{G(a_k) + G(b_k)}{2}$.
Furthermore, the author says that this $c$ can be chosen to be the farthest to the right in the interval.

However, I'm concerned that the set of such $c$'s could resemble $\left\{ b_k - 1/n \mid n \in \mathbb Z^+ \right\}$, suggesting that we might not be able to definitively choose the farthest right $c$ in the interval.
This possibility seems to challenge the author's assertion.

Could anyone provide clarification on why it is valid to select $c$ as the farthest right in the interval $(a_k, b_k)$?
I'm eager to understand this part of the proof and would appreciate any insights or explanations.

Comment: This is a pretty standard property of continuous functions. If $f:[a, b] \to\mathbb{R} $ is continuous and $p\in f([a, b]) $ then there is a largest value of $c\in[a, b] $ for which $f(c) =p$. Prove this by considering the set $A=\{x\mid x\in[a, b], f(x) =p\} $ and showing $A$ as closed.

Comment: Also if you think that $c$ could be like $b_k-1/n$ then by continuity $f(c) =f(b_k) $ which is a contradiction. Thats exactly what we mean when we say that set $A$ in previous comment is closed (ie contains its limit points). Here $b_k$ would be limit point of set $\{b_k-1/n\mid n\in \mathbb{N}, n\geq 1\} $.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Oh, my brain might have been left from my head for a while back then. Thank you so much to pick up my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Visualizing will help with this proof.

Think about the conditions of the set $E$. If you visualize it, then you will understand it's the set of points $x$ on the real line where there is (at least) one point to the right, $x + h$, such that $G(x + h)$ is higher than $G(x)$.

Now, think about what is NOT in $E$. If $y \not\in E$, then for every point to the right of $y$, $y + h$, we must have $G(y + h) \leq G(y)$. The way I'm visualizing this is if $y \not\in E$, then if $G$ was my altitude and I was walking (from *right to left*), $y$ is point at which $G(y)$ is the highest altitude I have reached so far.

By definition, $a_k < b_k$, we know $a_k, b_k \not\in E$, and $G(b_k) < G(a_k)$ (all laid out in the proof). Further we know that $G$ is monotone decreasing in the interval $(a_k, b_k)$, since otherwise it would contain points that are not in $E$.

[image: Invalid a_k and b_k]

[image: Valid a_k and b_k]
$$ \\ $$
The core continuity idea is that the function $G$ always has to tend back toward $G(b_k)$ eventually, which means it has to tend away from $\frac{G(a_k) + G(b_k)}{2}$, since by definition $G(b_k) < \frac{G(a_k) + G(b_k)}{2}$.
$$ \\ $$
[image: Continuity drawing]

Hope this helps!